# How to move a group within a column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My hypothetical sample is as follows:

```html
Group   Age Class
Yellow  12  A
Red:Green   18  A
Blue× Red   16  B
```

I want to move some colours in the Group column to get something like this:

```html
Group   Age Class
Red:Green   18  A
Yellow  12  A
Blue × Red  16  B
```

I have used these codes:

```html
df %>% group_by(Group)  %>% 
 Select(Red:Green, Yellow, Blue × Red)
```

But it seems it is a wrong code. It seems that arrange() does not work. I dont' know how to sort it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a vector with the order that you want and then use `match`.

```
vec <- c('Red:Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue×Red')
df1 <- df[match(vec, df$Group), ]
df1

#      Group Age Class
#2 Red:Green  18     A
#1    Yellow  12     A
#3  Blue×Red  16     B
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(match(vec, Group))
#df %>% slice(match(vec, Group))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c("Yellow", "Red:Green", "Blue×Red"), 
    Age = c(12L, 18L, 16L), Class = c("A", "A", "B")), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```